# My submit not working

Tags: asp.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp3Oj.png)

This is screenshot of page when i press submit button it gives dialog is not a function. When i click submit button it should open dialog box which i have created in which I ask user to enter its name and email but it is giving me this error.

```
var fired = 0;

        function myPop() {
            //alert('hello');
            event.preventDefault();
            //alert('hello2');
            if (fired == 0) {
                //alert('now i am inside');
                $("#dialogForInfo").dialog('open');
                alert('really');
                fired = 1;
            }
            return false;
        };

        $(function () {
            $("#dialogForInfo").dialog({
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false
            });
            $("#finaldialog2").dialog({
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false
            });

            $("#btnSubmitInfo").click(function () {
                $('#dialogForInfo').dialog('close');
                var dataValue = "{ Name: '" + $("#txtnoinput").val() + "', email: '" + $("#txtEmail").val() + "' }";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "index.aspx/SendParameters",
                    data: dataValue,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#finaldialog2').dialog('open');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Maybe look at the Error it is giving you?

Comment: feedback.aspx:84 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
    at myPop (feedback.aspx:84)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (feedback.aspx:703)

Comment: i have same popup working fine on my mobile version with same jquery and  html code

Comment: then show me where you add the jquery framework please

Comment: I updated my answer with a working code snippet. You need to call .dialog() and you need to check if your jquery is loaded correctly. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Check if you used jQuery correctly and change your Dialog call to:**

```js
  function myFunction() {

  $("#finaldialog2").dialog();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id="opener" onclick="myFunction()">open the dialog</button>
<div id="finaldialog2" title="Dialog Title" hidden="hidden">I'm a dialog</div>
```